# Mysql query with IF statement in WHERE?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to solve this problem, but I can't find right solution... What I want to do?

Now I'm joining main product with its cheapest variant. But I need to edit my query to do this:
Each variant has quantity_in_stock. If all variants has **quantity_in_stock == 0**, select the cheapest one, if there is any variant with **quantity_in_stock > 0**, select the cheapest one with **quantity_in_stock > 0**

Here is sample of code, where I need to use it:

```
$query = 'LEFT JOIN (
                     SELECT id_product_variant, price AS price, main_product_id FROM ' . $this->products_v_table . ' 
                           ORDER BY price ASC
                     ) as t1 ON t1.main_product_id = ' . $this->table_name . '.id_product ';
```

Do you have any ideas, how to do it? Thank you for your posts :)

Comment: You may be able to do it with an `order by` and a `limit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with a subquery that will give you the minimum price as you have specified for each main_product_id.  This does the trick using `COALESCE()` to take the first non-NULL item from its list of parameters.

The first parameter to `COALESCE()` is `MIN(IF(quantity_in_stock>0,price,NULL))`. This will kick back a null if there are no price values with corresponding positive quantity values.

The second parameter is `MIN(IF(quantity_in_stock=0,price,NULL))` This one gives the smallest price for zero quantity.

```
         SELECT COALESCE(
                    MIN(IF(quantity_in_stock>0, price, NULL)),
                    MIN(IF(quantity_in_stock=0, price, NULL))
                ) price,
                main_product_id
           FROM mytable
          GROUP BY main_product_id
```

It's wise to troubleshoot this subquery first to make sure it's giving appropriate results, one line per main_product_id.

Then you need to use this aggregate result set to choose the appropriate detail records -- the ones corresponding to the minimum prices -- from your main table.  That works like this.

```
SELECT mytable.*
  FROM mytable
  JOIN (
             SELECT COALESCE(
                      MIN(IF(quantity_in_stock>0, price, NULL)),
                      MIN(IF(quantity_in_stock=0, price, NULL))
                    ) price,
                    main_product_id
               FROM mytable
              GROUP BY main_product_id
       ) m USING(main_product_id,price)
```

**Edit** ... I am guessing at the name of your `mytable`.  It's not possible to tell the actual name of the table from your question. The error you're getting means what it says: one of your tables or subqueries needs a column called `main_product_id` but doesn't have it.  I suggest you echo or dump the value of $query right before you pass it to MySQL, and analyze it from there.

Comment: Oh, thank you man. It seams great. Anyway, if I tried to use it:
`$query = ' JOIN (
                    SELECT COALESCE(
                      MIN(IF(quantity_in_stock>0, price, NULL)),
                      MIN(IF(quantity_in_stock=0, price, NULL))
                    )price,
                    main_product_id
               FROM ' . $this->products_v_table . '
              GROUP BY main_product_id
       ) t1 USING(main_product_id,price)';`

SQL return: _#1054 - Unknown column 'main_product_id' in 'from clause'_

Comment: Thank you so much. You were right. I had fail in my query... Thank you @OllieJones

Comment: Please, is there any way, to select also **id_product_variant**, which has the selected price?

Comment: If `id_product_variant` appears in `mytable`, the query I wrote will select it.

Comment: I solved it via this tutorial:
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/